# Getting all values of an index in mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing

I'm working on a heatmap application which retrieves longitude and latitude points from a mysql database. Since the table I'm using is innodb I cannot use spatial index. So instead I divided the region where the points are located into a 1000*1000 block grid and assign each point an index based on the block it falls into using this formula:

```
set blockindex=FLOOR((lon-minlon)/londifference*1000)*1000+FLOOR(lat-minlat)/latdifference*1000);
```

Is there a syntax in mysql to get all the values in this index that's been assigned to a point?

Comment: Too many times use of the word "index". In dba language: Index is a database construct for creating faster access paths to data in the tables in the database. You seem to use index in at least two ways (the spacial index, and the assigned **index**), so what index are you referring to in your final question?

Comment: I did not use spatial index because it was an innodb table. I created an index using                                                                                                CREATE INDEX block_index
ON heatmappoints (blockindex);                                                                       where block index is the value calulated using the formula

Comment: A table index contains all values (except NULL values unless otherwise indicated) of the given to be indexed column. So the standard `CREATE TABLE` index should be sufficient for this cause.

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB 5.2 (etc) has ["Virtual Columns"](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/virtual-computed-columns/) , which can be indexed.

5.7.6 will have "functional indexes" by using ["Functional Expressions"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) .